Arts & Crafts is participating in an AI experiment
What's going on behind the scenes?
Arts & Crafts is currently participating in an experiment to evaluate possible uses of generative AI on Stack Exchange (link to relevant Meta post). Quote:

We’re working on an experiment to explore if/how Large Language Model (LLM) integration can support the human-curated knowledge repositories on Stack Exchange, in this case specifically around answers. The experiment, called “Answer Assistant” for now, is in its early stages, and we’ve been talking with moderators of several Stack Exchange communities who are interested in taking part in an experiment to test the concept.

Moderators were asked if they were interested in such an experiment and I volunteered.
But WHY???
Discussions about the quality of AI generated answers and whether or not to ban them entirely have been going on since the day ChatGPT went public. There is still no consensus within the entire network and due to low participation our own community poll was inconclusive.
I am very skeptical of AI in general and its use for Stack Exchange as a Q&A network, but I also have a scientific mind. I want to ban AI answers not because of a gut feeling, but based on objective numbers. I want to show the company that pursueing AI is a bad idea based on objective facts. If AI actually has any merit, I want to see objective proof instead of unrealistic promises. To do so, someone has to volunteer to generate these numbers and facts.
What has already happened?
At the moment of writing, this experiment had no effect on A&C.SE (that I know of). No answer on this site was AI generated by Stack Exchange.
All mods on Arts & Crafts were asked in chat to confirm their willingness to participate in this experiment. We were given access to a spreadsheet with AI generated answers to unanswered question from our site with the option to assess the factual correctness and the overall answer quality.
In case you noticed: Web Apps SE was the first site that proceeded with the next stage of the experiment and due to a bug some of the acitvity was exposed to users. Here's the relevant statement of the site mod and the discussion on Meta.
What's going to happen next?
As part of the next stage of the experiment, a new user profile "Answer Bot" with an AI tag will be created on this site. This bot will propose AI answers that are only visible to mods. The bot will only propose answers to questions from 2024 with a score of 0 or higher with no upvoted or accepted answer (the standard "unanswered" definition), and all new questions unanswered after 72 hours.
If there are no technical issues at this stage, the plan is to show the AI answer drafts to users in early january. We still have to decide which users (based on reputation) will see the answers, so your input is very welcome.
These AI answer drafts will not look like normal answers posted by humans users, instead they will be presented in an "Answer Assistant". AFAIK this Answer Assistant should give you the option to review the answer draft, propose edits to it and ultimately post it as a regular answer by "Answer Bot" (or just ignore it).
A help page will be created with an explaination of the Answer Assistant and a guide for those reviewing the draft answers.
